# different responsive display of tabular data

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, responsive-design, tabular

I want some tabular data to be displayed differently for different screen sizes:

- in one row on large displays: 
  A B C D E
- in two rows on small displays like this:

  B C D

  A E

What is the recommended way to do this in a rails app/view or pure css?

Comment: You can use Media Queries of CSS to achieve your purpose. Your requirement is basically of Responsive UI. Try to apply media queries. It will definitely help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the very fast answer. What I have no clue for is how to achieve the different ordering since I only edit css with media queries. Correct?